# How to use Lighthouse scoring Guide for Accessibility Audit?

Tags: performance, accessibility, seo-audit

I am working on scoring improvement on Accessibility Audit in Lighthouse.

My client's site has an accessibility score of 60 and they aim to get it 90+.

I performed the Audit using Google Lighthouse (available under Chrome Developer Tools) and found the exact pain points which needs to fix.

However, I want to make sure how much score I can get by fixing all these failing elements.

I checked the Lighthouse Scoring here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/scoring There is a Google SpreadSheet where we can add targeted values for each metric to find out the score.

Here is the SpreadSheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1up5rxd4EMCoMaxH8cppcK1x76n6HLx0e7jxb0e0FXvc/edit#gid=0

However, I couldn't find metric score values for Accessibility Audit metrices.

Please suggest how can I find these metric score values mentioned in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have metric score values like the Performance Score.
Each Accessibility test is a simple pass or fail with the particular category's weight contributing too the final score out of 100 for the Accessibility assessment

> **The Accessibility score is a weighted average of all the accessibility
>   audits.** See Scoring Details for a full list of how each audit is
>   weighted. The heavier-weighted audits have a bigger impact on your
>   score.
>
> **Each accessibility audit is pass or fail. Unlike the Performance audits, a page doesn't get points for partially passing an
>   accessibility audit. For example, if some elements have
>   screenreader-friendly names, but others don't, that page gets a 0 for
>   the screenreader-friendly-names audit.**